# Converting a string into array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string like this:

```
$values = "[121],[622],[872]";
```

I would like to convert this into an array, I would like each number in the square brackets to be an array item.

any suggestions how I can do this?

Comment: Have you looked at functions like explode() and str_replace(); or preg_match()?

Answer (score 4):

```
$array = explode(',',str_replace(array('[',']'),array('',''),$values));
```

Answer (score 3):

Seriously? Use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$values = "[121],[622],[872]";
$values = str_replace(array("[", "]"), "", $values);
$values = explode(",", $values);
```

Or in a simpler way:

```
$array = explode("," ,str_replace(array("[", "]"), "", $values));
```

This gives values as:

```
Array
  121
  622
  872
```

Comment: Seriously? you read the question? You need a regex here before exploding, he just needs numbers...

Comment: @Mr.Alien Done, using simple `str_replace`.

Comment: took back the -1 too :)

Comment: LOL awarded to ikkez :p

Answer (score 0):

See This

```
$values = "[121],[622],[872]";
$values = substr($values,1);
$values = substr($values,0,-1);
$arr = explode("],[",$values);
```

Hope this helps